# LDAP injection vulnerability with DirectoryEntry username and password?

Tags: c#, ldap, directoryservices, checkmarx

As part as an authentication procedure, we build a `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry` from a user name and password input by the user:

```cs
    var de = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPathFromConfig, typedUserName, typedPassword, AuthenticationTypes.ReadonlyServer|AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```

But when we run the code through **Checkmarx**, it claims there's are "LDAP injection" vulnerabilities on `typedUserName` and `typedPassword` because they are not sanitized. I don't understand why, since by definition a password can be *anything*... And the [constructor used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.-ctor?view=netframework-4.0#System_DirectoryServices_DirectoryEntry__ctor_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_DirectoryServices_AuthenticationTypes_) is clearly meant to accept a `username` and `password` as second and third parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For Checkmarx, you should always sanitize (validate) each value you use. If you don't do it, Checkmarx see it as untrusted and by the way and the Checkmarx rules, this could  goes to some injection. In your case, this is a normal finding from Checkmarx.

LDAP injection are commons, like SQL Injection, and as I remember, there is not solution like Parametrization for LDAP (see https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/LDAP_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) .

Comment: So, what should I do? Am I supposed to escape special characters? But does `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry` expect an escaped string, or will it instead fail to match passwords? Because as I said, this is not a Distinguished Name nor a filter string. The constructor is documented as expecting a password, plain and simple.

Comment: I m not sure but I think it does not expect an escaped string . This should be in the same format that the format who is stored in the LDAP tree. So if the password has been escaped and store escaped, this should work

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue as the original post. My research seems to indicate that a textual password should be escaped. Here is the relevant paragraph from RFC 4511 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#section-4.2):

```
 Textual passwords (consisting of a character sequence with a known
 character set and encoding) transferred to the server using the
 simple AuthenticationChoice SHALL be transferred as UTF-8 [RFC3629]
 encoded [Unicode].  Prior to transfer, clients SHOULD prepare text
 passwords as "query" strings by applying the SASLprep [RFC4013]
 profile of the stringprep [RFC3454] algorithm.  Passwords
 consisting of other data (such as random octets) MUST NOT be
 altered.  The determination of whether a password is textual is a
 local client matter.
```

Note that it states that the 'client should prepare text passwords as "query" strings' and references other standards to define how.